# Checking a calculated value with case expression

Tags: sql

I have a query such as:

```
SELECT *,
(A+B) AS TOTALVALUE
FROM 
(SELECT A,B FROM MYTABLE) AS MYTABLE1
```

How can I use a `case...when` with the calculated value? For example, if my calculated value is greater than 1 I want it to be 10, otherwise I want it to return its value. How can i achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried? Start from the examples in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
, (A+B) AS TOTAL VALUE
, case when (A + B) > 1 then 10 else (A + B) end as my_calc_col
FROM MYTABLE
```

You might also want to consider `NULLs`:

```
select 
     x.A
   , x.B
   , case when TOTAL_VALUE > 1 then 10 else TOTAL_VALUE end as TOTAL_VALUE2
from
(
   select coalesce(A, 0) + coalesce(B, 0) as TOTAL_VALUE
          , A
          , B
   FROM MYTABLE
) x
```

**EDIT**: I've also simplified this bit:

```
FROM 
(SELECT A,B FROM MY TABLE) AS MYTABLE1
```

as simply:

```
SELECT A, B, .....
FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   *,
   CASE WHEN 
      (A+B) > 1 
   THEN 
     10 
   ELSE 
     (A+B) END
 AS TOTAL VALUE
FROM 
(SELECT A,B FROM MY TABLE) AS MYTABLE1
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers it might be worth pointing out that there are two types of CASE  in SQL Server

These are equivalent

```
CASE x
   WHEN y THEN z
   ELSE NULL
END
```

and

```
CASE 
   WHEN x = y THEN z
   ELSE NULL
END
```

but you can't do an expression with the first as far as I know:

e.g. the second case statement could do:

```
CASE 
   WHEN x + 1 = y - 1 THEN z
   ELSE NULL
END
```

The use of expressions in the second case statement is useful, but if you need a simple value comparison, use the first.